# Positoning a UI Image " In Between " the text of UI Label

Tags: ios, swift

My app takes some text data from a web server using API

The text data comes in an array of string. Basically each element is a paragraph. Some times one of the array element is "[IMAGE]" , which means I have to insert a particular image (whose link I also obtain using API) in between the previous and the next para

So for ex the array is [ "AAA" , "BBB" , "[IMAGE]" , "CCC" ]. Then the image has to be displayed in between BBB and CCC

This is where I obtain the response from web server

```
let newsText = data[0]["text"] as! [String]
let images = data[0]["images"] as! [[String:Any]]
```

This is what I've done

```
for para in newsText{
                    if(para == "[IMAGE]")
                    {
                        print("Image Found")
                        let paraImageLink = images[self.imageCount]["link"] as? String
                        let paraImage = self.urlToImage(url: paraImageLink!)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let paraImageView = UIImageView(image: paraImage)
                            paraImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
                            self.view.addSubview(paraImageView)
                        }
                        self.imageCount+=1
                    }
                    else{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.text.text?.append(contentsOf: para+"\n\n\n")
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Now the image is retrieved and displayed successfully ,  but it is displayed at the corner of the screen. Which is correct because I put X:0 , Y: 0

But my question is how would I position the image correctly to achieve what I want

This is a screenshot of my simulator , the image is on the top right corner and I want to display it between the paragraphs

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGwsf.jpg)

Everything is inside a UI Scroll View , and all the Text below the main image (not the corner one) is in a single UI label

EDIT :

I tried to use Attributed String with attachment as such

```
 for para in newsText{
                    if(para == "[IMAGE]")
                    {
                        print("Image Found")
                        let paraImageLink = images[self.imageCount]["link"] as? String
                        let paraImage = self.urlToImage(url: paraImageLink!)
                        let imageAttachement = NSTextAttachment()
                        imageAttachement.image = paraImage
                        let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachement)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            self.text.attributedText = imageString
                        }
                        self.imageCount+=1
                    }
                    else{
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.text.text?.append(contentsOf: para+"\n\n")
                        }
```

Problem is it doesn't produce the desired result. Check this screenshot to see what it displays[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw898.jpg).

I guess it is because you can't append the UI label attributed text , if I try to do this

```
self.text.attributedText.append = imageString
```

It shows the error 
Value of type 'NSAttributedString?' has no member 'append'

Comment: Can you give the screenshot where it hookup now ??

Comment: I have the screenshot in my question , the image in the top left corner is the one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using an attribute string Like this .
First create emptyString varible than when you get string add it to this varible when your get image add it to as NSTextAttachmen

`var text = String()`

1. When get image then create attribute attachment like :

`let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()`

2.than add your image to attachment like: 
 `imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: paraImage)`

3. wrap your attchment like : 
   `let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)`
   4.then add the textAttribute attchment to your full string like

`text.append(image1String)` 
5. then append othre text string to your full string like this

`text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "End of"))`
6.then add your string to your textView like this

`textView.attributedText = text`

For batter understand your can see this [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-insert-images-into-an-attributed-string-with-nstextattachment)